# how to apply key-decode-fn only to top level keys while json unmarshaling using metosin

Tags: clojure

I've a requirement where I can decode only keys.

consider the below example -

```clj
(require '[jsonista.core :as json])
(import
 (com.fasterxml.jackson.core JsonFactory$Feature)
 (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind ObjectMapper)
 (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda JodaModule))

(def s "{\"name\":\"person1\",\"book\":\"Demo Book\",\"hash\":{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\",\"key3\":\"value3\"}}")

(def ^ObjectMapper object-mapper
  (let [obj-mapper (json/object-mapper {:decode-key-fn true :modules [(JodaModule.)]})]
    (doto obj-mapper
      (-> .getFactory (.disable JsonFactory$Feature/USE_THREAD_LOCAL_FOR_BUFFER_RECYCLING)))
    obj-mapper))

(json/read-value s object-mapper)
```

The output I would like to get is

```json
{:book "Demo Book", :name "person1", :hash {"key3" "value3", "key2" "value2", "key1" "value1"}}
```

In the json above, the top level is converted to keys and nested are not converted to keys but kept as string.

`:decode-key-fn true` make all keys and without `:decode-key-fn true` all keys are strings which is not I want. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Are you sure that key `name` should be a string, even if it's on the same level as `book` and `hash`? (You could use `(update-keys ... keyword)` if you want to convert all three keys.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert all keys and only on the top level, you can use [`update-keys`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/update-keys):

```
(-> (json/read-value s object-mapper)
    (update-keys keyword))
```

With that, set `:decode-key-fn` in `object-mapper` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do the conversion in two steps: first, parse the json with string keys, and then convert some of the keys to keywords.

Using [clojure.set/rename-keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/rename-keys) for the second step as such:

```
(defn keywordize [m]
   (rename-keys m {"book" :book, "hash" :hash, "name" :name}))
```

Or to automatically convert all keys from the first level:

```
(defn keywordize [m]
  (rename-keys m (zipmap (keys m) (map keyword (keys m)))))
```